# Faster Disk side of the HDD

Tags: performance, disk, file-transfer

So the internet is saying that the inner part of the disk is FASTER then the outside of it. Now do explain me that this is right and if it is right please tell me how to transfer my data to the beginning. Even if you can transfer only Windows OS files.

Comment: The difference in rotation speed is minimal. If you want speed, get a small SSD to use as a boot drive. And Linux caches apps into RAM, so if you have extra RAM it keeps last used apps in RAM and only releases those if you load newer apps and space is needed. Users often load same app again, so saves reading from drive again.

Answer (score 1):

The innermost part of a physical disk platter has the slowest transfer rate and increases to the outside. There is a greater surface area per track on the outside resulting in more sectors the head passes with each rotation (see [Zone Bit Recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_bit_recording)).

Since the layout (track 0, sector 0) starts at the outside of the disk, your fastest partition is the first one. Use a partitioning program like GParted to move your fast data partition to the "beginning" of the disk.